# Entity SaveChanges is overriding subsequent entities Id values

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have a for loop to generate multiple entities and save into database.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
    Unit unit = new Unit();
    unit.id = 0; //autogenerated value
    _context.Unit.Add(unit);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    Item item = new Item();
    item.unitid = unit.id;
    _context.Item.Add(item);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In this scenario assuming the unit outputs ids of 1,2,3
I'm assuming the item.unitid should therefore be three items, and individually have unitid values of 1,2,3 separately

What in fact happens, I have three items with unitid of 3 and saved to database.

I've tried combinations of saveChanges within and outside the loop. also used EntityState.added but similar outcome.

Comment: You should work with navigation properties, for example `Item.Unit = unit`. Then there's no need to set these `id` properties and do multiple `SaveChanges` calls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but your code is working fine probably you have a problem else where or with your test statements... here is my test

```
        var Context = new Test2Context();

        foreach(var Item in Context.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Item.id);
            Console.WriteLine(Item.unitid);

        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (var unit in Context.Units)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(unit.id);

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            Unit unit = new Unit();
            unit.id = 0;//autogenerated value
            Context.Units.Add(unit);
            Context.SaveChanges();

            Item item = new Item();
            item.unitid = unit.id;
            
            Context.Items.Add(item);
            Context.SaveChanges();


            Console.WriteLine(unit.id);
            Console.WriteLine(item.unitid);
            Console.WriteLine(item.id);
            Console.WriteLine();
```